# port forwarding in docker container in AWS EC2 linux machine

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm a newbie and needing help. Currently playing with the following setup:
remote machine
  an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18.

I am trying to access Jupyter notebook running in Docker container in AWS EC2 machine but not able to access it. 
Time out Error

i tried the following command for port tunnelling i read somewhere

ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 -i /home/user/admin_keypair.pem  ec2user@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

but getting this error

Warning: Identity file /home/user/admin_keypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: How do you usually connect to instance via SSH? (just to access terminal)

Comment: ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
using this command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the path to your .pem file within double quotes, see below.

I had something similar, adding the -4 flag worked for me, by default it was using ipv6 and I did not have it enabled.

```
ssh -4 -L 8080:localhost:8080 -i "/home/user/admin_keypair.pem" ec2user@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And anyone else who may have an issue, adding the flag -v will output debugging info that might help you figure out why it was not working.

```
ssh -4 -v -L 8080:localhost:8080 -i "/home/user/admin_keypair.pem" ec2user@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```